# Multiple calls to a controller's function causes problems (EF Core in an ASP.NET MVC web app)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, controller, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core in an ASP.NET MVC web app.

It is an online restaurant. I want to let the user to change the quantity of a cart item (only adding more in this point) and by that to update his `cartItemPrice` and also his `cartTotalPrice` (a cart can contain few cart items and every cart item can contain few dishes).

After testing the code, it is working fine, only if I call `AddOne` method one at the time, the `cartItemPrice` and the `CartTotalPrice` are both update as should be.

The problem starts when I call the method many times (by clicking fast.. double clicking for instance causing the problem).

The problem causes the `cartItemPrice` to change sometimes, and sometimes not while the `CartTotalPrice` changes always.

I used this tag for calling the `AddOne` method from the View/Carts :

```
 <div class="quantity">
 <a asp-action="AddOne" asp-controller="Carts" asp-route-id="@ci.Id" class="add quantity-btn col-3">+</a>
 </div>
```

I tried to use async and await and also without them and both ways gave the same bad result.

The functions from the Controllers/CartsController:

async/await:

```
public async Task AddToTotalPrice(double price)
{
    var user = GetCurrentUserName();
    var cart = await _context.Cart.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.UserName == user);
    cart.CartTotalPrice += price;
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

public async Task AddOne(int id)
{
    var cartitem = await _context.CartItem.Include(d => d.Dish).FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
    var u = GetCurrentUserName();
    var c = _context.Cart.FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserName == u);

    if (cartitem != null)
    {
        if (cartitem.CartId != c.Id)
        {
            return;
        }

        cartitem.Quantity += 1;
        cartitem.cartItemPrice = cartitem.Dish.Price * cartitem.Quantity;
        await AddToTotalPrice(cartitem.Dish.Price);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Without async/await:

```
public void AddToTotalPrice(double price)
{
    var user = GetCurrentUserName();
    var cart = _context.Cart.FirstOrDefault(s => s.UserName == user);
    cart.cartTotalPrice += price;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}

public void AddOne(int id)
{
    var cartitem = _context.CartItem.Include(d => d.Dish).FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
    var u = GetCurrentUserName();
    var c = _context.Cart.FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserName == u);

    if (cartitem != null)
    {
        if (cartitem.CartId != c.Id)
        {
            return;
        }

        cartitem.Quantity += 1;
        cartitem.cartItemPrice = cartitem.Dish.Price * cartitem.Quantity;
        AddToTotalPrice(cartitem.Dish.Price);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

What is wrong here and if it possible to fix?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) add concurrency columns to your schema. 2) Call save changes once, or within a transaction. 3) catch and retry the request. And/Or compute the total price on demand via a query.

Comment: it seems that [ConcurrencyCheck] fixed it. thank you @JeremyLakeman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While server processes one request another request is doing the same thing and you have data race.

You can solve this by two ways:

**Transaction**

```cs
public async Task AddToTotalPrice(double price)
{
    var user = GetCurrentUserName();
    var cart = await _context.Cart.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.UserName == user);
    cart.CartTotalPrice += price;
}

public async Task AddOne(int id)
{
    using var tran = _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
    
    var cartitem = await _context.CartItem.Include(d => d.Dish).FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
    var u = GetCurrentUserName();
    var c = _context.Cart.FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserName == u);

    if (cartitem != null)
    {
        if (cartitem.CartId != c.Id)
        {
            return;
        }

        cartitem.Quantity += 1;
        cartitem.cartItemPrice = cartitem.Dish.Price * cartitem.Quantity;
        await AddToTotalPrice(cartitem.Dish.Price);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    await tran.CommitAsync();
}
```

**Concurrency Token**

Add to `Cart.CartTotalPrice` attribute `[ConcurrencyCheck]` as specified in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations).

And catch `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` and restart updating price again. [Handling Concurrency Conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency)

Comment: it seems that  [ConcurrencyCheck] fixed it. thank you